# What font is AU using?

Tags: discussion

This is more of a site question, but what font is this site using? I'd like to make it my desktop font too, it's rather interesting and looks nice.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the CSS files for the site, it appears that the preferred font is the Ubuntu font, which you should find on your machine in `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu-font-family`

**Edit**

To use the font on your site, you would have to convert it to a Web Font, as the developers of AU did. Here's a snippet of their CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Ubuntu';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
    src: url('img/ubuntu-L-webfont.eot');
    src: local('Ubuntu Light'), local('Ubuntu-Light'), url('img/ubuntu-L-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('img/ubuntu-L-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('img/ubuntu-L-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('img/ubuntu-L-webfont.svg#UbuntuLight') format('svg');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'UbuntuRegular';
    src: url('img/ubuntu-R-webfont.eot');
    src: url('img/ubuntu-R-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('img/ubuntu-R-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('img/ubuntu-R-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('img/ubuntu-R-webfont.svg#UbuntuRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

You would have to do your own searching for converting to Web Fonts - not something that I have done.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how I can add this to my site's CSS? Right now my CSS I put as:  font-family: "times new roman", times, roman, serif;

Comment: this would be better fitted in stackoverflow...

Comment: @MikeKuplevatsky See my edits.

Comment: @the_Seppi I would tend to agree. Flag it if you want.